# Add multiple command-keys to folder in registry editor

Tags: windows-registry

I coded a program for deleting files/folder. Now I wanted to right click on them and see the option "delete". My first question (beside the topic) is, how can I add the name of the item I have clicked on to "delete". So there should be look like "delete file.txt".
Anyway, after I managed to add my .exe file, I saw that some programmes have multiple options to execute.

[multiple options for executing a program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1KMF.png)

Sorry for the German language but I think you get the point.

Edit: Explanation: I have a delete.exe. There are three modi to delete a clicked item. 1 => Weak deletion; 2; 3 => Strong deletion. My goal is that when I click for example on my "Matura"-Folder as shown in the picture above, multiple options what I wanna do with my "delete" show up. (In 7-Zip there are Add to archive, Add to archive & send to, ...). In delete there would be delete with modi 1, modi 2, modi 3 and so on.

```
delete >
            delete 1
            delete 2
            delete 3
            _other-options_
           ...
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I eddited my question. I hope, it is now better understandable.